# fprintf with an Integer with value = zero

Tags: c, file-io

I must be using an inappropriate argument in fprintf (specifier or perhaps one of the other ones) because my output does not make sense.

```
// based on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/
{
FILE * pFile;

int edam7514 = gPlace[7514].damage;

int fdam4677 = gPlace[4677].damage;

pFile = fopen("Z:\\Games\\Game_1.8.11.26dev\\SAVE\\debugLog.txt", "a");

fprintf(pFile, "edam7514, %.d, fdam4677, %.d\n", edam7514, fdam4677);

fclose(pFile);
return 0;
}
```

"gPlace" is an array of struct. There are several thousand active in the game. Elements 7514 and 4677 represent combat regiments (Hundred Years War), and both have a "damage" field that can range from 0 to 100.

This code is being used in testing artillery bombardment against the English regiment (7514) but not against the French one (4677).

The values at the time of fprintf execution are:
int edam7514 = 99
int fdam4677 = 0
(I have checked this by looking at the actual values in the data structures during debugging)

Nonetheless, the following is what is in the file that is produced:

```
edam7514, 99, fdam4677,
```

I was expecting:

```
edam7514, 99, fdam4677, 0
```

I guess I have not formatted my arguments in the fprintf function call properly?

Comment: Why `%.d`? The reference I checked with suggests the period should be followed by a number.

Comment: What do you think `%.d` does?

Comment: A key issue is that your compiler _should_ have warned you about this.  Insure your compiler has its warnings fully enabled.  Saves time.

Comment: And next time, you could save us a lot reading by providing a minimal example. All the game context is irrelevant in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected output for that format string. If you didn't want that output, you probably shouldn't have put `.` between `%` and `d`.

A `.` there with no integer or `*` following it specifies a *precision* value of 0, which for the `d` conversion specifier, means that no characters will be printed for a `0` argument.

If you're ever confused about the behavior of fprintf, remember that you can always just [look it up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Thanks user, very helpful!